# Буква Ё вообще когда-нибудь писалась в суффиксах и окончаниях существительных после шипящих?

Tags: орфография

Не всё так ясно с  О/Ё  после шипящими.

1) Чередование Е/Ё всегда связано с **изменением ударения.**
 До появления буквы Ё  (последняя четверть 18 века) мы наблюдаем после шипящих **чередование Е/О** при колебании ударения (переходе от безударной позиции к ударной):  меч - мЕчем – мечОм,   плащ - плАщем – плащом, парча – пАрчевый – парчОвый.

2) С появлением буквы Ё  ничего не изменяется, по-прежнему в ударной позиции после шипящих пишется буква О, буква Ё после шипящих практически не употреблялась.

**Разовые употребления Ё или случайны  (например, крючёк:  1 пример на 46 примеров), или ошибочны (в современной литературе).**

В словах волчонок, девчонка, собачонка писалась и пишется  только О.

4) Возможны варианты:  казАчек – казАчека и казачок  - казачка. Разные написания связаны с формой, а не семантикой слова.

Примеры:

Я облек себя **плащом**, который от мокроты весил с добрый богатырский панцирь, и уладился было на седле, проникнутом водой, как губка… [И. И. Лажечников. Гримаса моего доктора (1813)]

Холодный северозападный ветер дул с самого утра и значительно понизил температуру воздуха, так что я прозяб под суконным **плащем** [А. А. Рафалович. Путешествие по Нижнему Египту и внутренним областям Дельты (1850)]

Все обращение его, впрочем, было дико, одевание странно: он носил с фраком **парчовый** камзол, подпоясывался розовым кушаком шелковым, обувался в белыечулки, на башмаках носил бантики и длинную повязывал прусскую косу. [И. М. Долгоруков., 1788-го года в августе месяце,

Косы, заплетенные в дрибушки или перевитые разноцветными скиндячками, радужная плахта, штофовый или **парчевый** корсет, [О. М. Сомов. Гайдамак (1825)] 
Мы опасались, чтоб **крючёк** не разогнулся,  [Ф. Ф. Беллинсгаузен. Двукратные изыскания в Южном Ледовитом океане (1831)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вышний Волочёк - до сих пор пишется. Существовало общее веяние или нет, можно проследить только по старым изданиям.

Comment: Имена собственные - это не показатель, по правилам орфографии  русские фамилии и сейчас свободно пишутся через ОВ/ЁВ после шипящих. Что касается веяний, то я ориентировалась на Нацкорпус, там написания Ё после шипящих в именных суффиксах и окончаниях практически не встречаются. Вы можете предложить другую статистику?

Comment: Статистику в сети можно набрать только современную: большая часть результатов поиска будет относиться к переизданным текстам, а старых отсканированных слишком мало, чтобы добраться до шипящих при нужных обстоятельствах. Думаю, что буква "ё" появилась с изменениями в произношении, не обязательно связанными с ударением. В старом языке не было не только этой буквы, но и известного нам звука (считается ошибкой его воспроизведение при чтении старославянских текстов).  Известный пример старого ударного произношения (через "е" - из рифмы): "Когда в товарищах согласья нет, на лад их дело не пойдет".

Comment: Когда потребовалось приводить написание в соответствие произношением, появилась новая буква. Разумеется, потребность возникла не от слов типа "чорт", но по какому пути во времена внедрения "ё" шла циркулярная грамматика (не распространилось ли это на такие слова), по переизданным текстам не определить. Возможно, и был переходный период "расширенного" применения. Если не ограничиваться окончаниями и суффиксами существительных, то в прочих современных случаях "ё" уверенно применяется (расчёска, сгущёнка, печёнка, тушёнка...).

Answer (score 0):

> Чередование Е/Ё всегда связано с изменением ударения.

**Неправильное утверждение!**

> В словах волчонок, девчонка, собачонка писалась и пишется только О.

**Нет, не так!** См. словари 19-го века:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=================================

> меч - мЕчем – мечОм

Несколько примеров с иным написанием:

===

*И онъ мнѣ грудь разсѣкъ **мечёмъ**,*

*И сердце трепетное вынулъ,*

*И угль, пылающій огнёмъ,*

*Во грудь отверстую водвинулъ.*

===

*Когда, **мечёмъ** грозя Литвѣ,*

*Являлся латникъ въ дальнемъ полѣ...*

===

*Лишь пальцемъ до него дотронься, забіяка,*

*Тебѣ своимъ **мечёмъ** я брюхо пропорю.*

===================================

> плащ - плАщем – плащом

===

*Скажи, какъ въ двадцать лѣтъ любовникъ подъ окномъ*

*Трепещетъ и кипитъ, окутанный **плащёмъ**.*

Comment: Вы когда-нибудь встречали Ё в безударной позиции? Тогда у меня такой вопрос: А Вы вообще различаете  фонемную единицу О/Ё/Е  (например, суффикс ОК/ЁК/ЕК) и отдельную фонему Е? И почему у Вас всё словари да словари, приведите текстовые примеры с реальными написаниями (ИМЕННО ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ ОБСУЖДАЕТСЯ).  И еще дополнительный вопрос: какое максимальное количество восклицательных знаков допускается ставить в конце одного слова? Два или три? Вы, наверное, знаете.

Comment: _Vera: "Вы когда-нибудь встречали Ё в безударной позиции?"_ === А при чём здесь это? Как **это** связано с Вашим утверждением "Чередование Е/Ё всегда связано с изменением ударения"? Но коль такой вопрос задан -- отвечу. ВСТРЕЧАЛ. И Вы встречали, только не замечали. ЁФИКАТОР, ЁФИКАЦИЯ -- на какой слог Вы ставите ударение? На первый? Сочувствую...=== ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ.  В "Русском орфографическом словаре" (2012) ударение в этих словах -- на третьем слоге.

Comment: slava, может быть, обратили внимание, здесь однажды появился участник, который обратился ко мне со словами "избавьте меня от своего агро (Агро (Aggro) -агрессия, враждебность), хотя я просто и совсем не агрессивно излагала свою точку зрения. Поэтому я предлагаю: давайте с Вами общаться без  "агро" или не общаться совсем. Мы могли бы обсудить Ваши интересные замечания и сведения о словарях, это было бы интересно и полезно и нам, и всем остальным, но,  сожалению,  как-то сложно вести с Вами конструктивный диалог. Желаю Вам проявлять больше дружелюбия к окружающим Вас людям.

Comment: "Но когда вижу чушь, излагаемую с апломбом".   slava, боюсь, что за вами может прийти модератор, а вы нет? Отчаянный  Вы человек, просто восхищаюсь.

Comment: Лучше за Вами...  И коль Вам кто-то из участников, как я узнал из Ваших слов, написал "избавьте меня от своего агро" -- задумайтесь над его словами.

Comment: Я никогда не пользуюсь на форуме оскорбительной лексикой, как и все приличные люди,  к которым до сегодняшнего дня я относила и Вас. А такие выражения, да еще на таком строгом ресурсе не часто услышишь, вы меня просто развеселили.

Comment: _Vera: "…к которым до сегодняшнего дня я относила и Вас."_ === Гм… И что же произошло сегодня? А, да… Я в своём ответе попытался опровергнуть Ваши ошибочные утверждения  словами "Неправильное утверждение!", "Нет, не так!" И это Вас просто взорвало: _"А Вы вообще различаете фонемную единицу О/Ё/Е... и отдельную фонему Е? И почему у Вас всё словари да словари, приведите текстовые примеры с реальными написаниями (ИМЕННО ЭТО ЗДЕСЬ ОБСУЖДАЕТСЯ). И еще дополнительный вопрос: какое максимальное количество восклицательных знаков допускается ставить в конце одного слова? Два или три?"_

Comment: Меня просто удивил набор эмоций с восклицаниями вместо ответа, поэтому я попыталась задать наводящие вопросы, которые Вы не поняли. Итак,  я думаю, что мы уже всё сказали друг другу и теперь  однозначно предлагаю не общаться совсем. Будем существовать в разных  Вселенных, надеюсь, что Вы не против (отвечать не нужно).

Comment: «См. словари 19-го века». Может быть, станем писать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Статистика по Нацкорпусу, 5 периодов

1) до 1800 г  2) 1800-1850,  3) 1850 – 1900, 4) 1900 – 1956, 5) 1956 – 2015

Контрольные слова: **котенок, мышонок, собачонка, девчонка**.

**Выводы:**

1) **Котенок.** Практически стабильная форма.  До 1956 года всего две формы «котёнок», после 1956 года – 15 (Ё) : 390 (Е).

2) **Мышонок** – единственная форма.

3) **Собачонка.** До 1900 года единственная форма, в период 1900 – 1956 появляется форма «собаченка» - 7 примеров, собачонка- 172 примера. После 1956 года – только собачонка (179 примеров).

4) **Девчонка.** Картина аналогичная: в период 1900 – 1956 появляется форма «девченка» - 8 примеров, девчонка -  671 пример. После 1956 года: девчонка – 1485 примеров, девчёнка -3 примера, девченка – 7 примеров.

Итак, **появление буквы Ё фактически не отразилось на практическом письме для шипящих в суффиксах именных форм.** В ударной позиции после любых шипящих  писалась буква О, кроме отдельных исключений. **Такое традиционное письмо было закреплено правилами 1956 года.**

Примечание

В настоящее время буква Ё пишется в двух случаях: в корнях с чередованием Е/Ё и в глаголах и глагольных формах (причастиях, отглагольных прилагательных и т.д.) .  **Менять эту ситуацию ни в коем случае нельзя,** так как буква Ё сохраняет **привычную форму написания этих слов:** темнеть – тёмный, чернеть – чёрный,  несёт – течёт – стрижёт, унесённый – зажжённый.